# Understanding reads from a named pipe

Tags: c, fifo

First off, why does the `main` loop only call `getfifo` when data is sent? Being in `while (true)`, I would have expected it to keep looping.

Second, when data is sent, the first thing that's hit is the `read(c2s, &buf, MAX_BUF)`, then main `loop->getfifo()` then the fifo func. That just seems out of order. Can someone please explain this?

Lastly, is this the correct way to lay out the code? I will have a main continuous loop that will run many different pieces when finished, but the order everything seems to run makes me feel I did something wrong.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (stat(myfifo, &st) != 0)
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

  while (true)
    getfifo();

  unlink(myfifo);
}


void getfifo()
{
  char buf[MAX_BUF] = "";
  /* open the FIFO (named pipe) */
  int c2s = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

  // if there is data on the pipe we read it in buf
  if (read(c2s, &buf, MAX_BUF) > 0) {
    printf("FIFO Received: %s\n", buf);
    // do something with the received data
    // TODO: parse it and send it over to slaves
  }
  sleep(1);

  close(c2s);
}
```

Sorry if this is basic, this is my first C++ program in over a decade and like to really understand what I am doing, not just make it work.

Comment: Well, too much has changed in a decade :).

Comment: First off, why do you think that? Where is your proof? It's more likely you are suffering from not flushing _stdout_.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the order of events is what you say. The program starts in main, so it does 1. stat. 2. conditionally mkfifo. 3. forever: { 3.1 call getfifo(). 3.2. In getfifo: open() fifo. 3.3. In getfifo(): read(), probably **blocking.** 3.4. in getfifo: conditionally printf(). 3.5. In getfifo: sleep() and close(). 3.6 return from getfifo().  } I'm not particularily familiar with fifos but this doesn't sound crazy. Note that a blocking read prevents the program from running until data arrives. By the way, I fail to see many C++ specifics ;-).

Comment: Btw, you need to test for EOF/read errors or the program never ends unless you kill it. The fifo will never be unlinked.

Comment: Thanks. Peter. I think I understand what I did wrong by your description. Fifo is blocking it for going back to the main loop. How would I fix that so the main can keep looping? I will have a few other pieces that need to be in a continuous loop.

Comment: There is literally nothing in this that is C++. Can it be flagged as C instead?

Comment: Yea, the order just looked wrong because of the blocking. I will put it into a different thread unless there is a better way.

Comment: Consider learning to use gdb or lldb if using clang, and step through your code. This will illustrate exactly what is happening with great detail.

Comment: What other things do you expect to react to in your main loop? Are they file descriptors? If so, you can poll() them for readiness.

Comment: The main loop is going to be grabbing sensor data and outputting data to devices constantly. This piece is just so I can send more data to it from another program. @Hack Saw, I am using gdb, but it would just lock up basically until I sent a command, didn't find anywhere it said it was blocked/waiting.

Comment: Nonblocking I/O is possible by using the `fcntl(2)` `F_SETFL` operation to enable the O_NONBLOCK open file status flag.

Comment: Or you can add O_NONBLOCK to the open call: open(myfifo, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)